# Grails - hasMany has too many, need to limit get() results in Oracle

Tags: oracle, grails, pagination, grails-orm

I am using Oracle and Grails 1.3.7 and have this situation:

**Domains**

```
class Publisher {
  static hasMany = [books : Book]
}
class Book {
  Publisher pub
  Date datePublished
}
```

**PublisherController**

```
def show = {
   def publisherInstance = Publisher.get(params.id)
   ...
}
```

Let's pretend that each publisher has thousands of books. After the Publisher.get(params.id) publisherInstance will have tons of books attached to it. In the controller show action is it possible to paginate the books displayed by datePublished?  I'm playing with withCriteria but haven't had any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you load the Publisher, the books don't get loaded until you access the `books` collection - it's lazily loaded on-demand for exactly this reason. If you want to retrieve a few of the Publisher's books, use a query, e.g.

```
def publisherInstance = Publisher.get(params.id)

int offset = ...
def books = Book.findAllByPublisher(publisherInstance, [max: 10, offset: offset])
```

and to select the correct page, calculate `offset` from the pagination parameters.

Comment: We also went from `has(Too)Many` to explicit criteria/finders. Great amounts of data require special handling, you won't be able to think of it every time when accessing `books` field.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the dynamic finder, in general case you can use criteria:

```
class Book {
      static belongsTo = [publisher: Publisher]
}
```

And to get the list of 10 first books of publisher "2"

```
offset = 0
// Get books of publisher
def queryResult = Book.createCriteria().list(max: 10, offset: offset) {                 
                publisher {
                    eq("id", 2)
                }
            }
```